# Image showing up in VS design mode, but not in browser

Tags: asp.net, html, css

Okay so I have a simple HTML Input fragment:

```
<input id="txtFirstName" type="text" class="txtBox" runat="server" />
```

Which is hooked up to this CSS property:

```
.txtBox
{

    background: url("/Images/lu/input_bg.png") repeat-x scroll left bottom transparent;
    border: 1px solid #E0E6EF;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 275px;

}
```

The image shows up in Visual Studios design window, but not when I view it in a browser.  What gives?

Comment: Are you sure the deployed site is at the root of your web server? It could be that locally you have it deployed to the root, e.g. http://localhost:8012/Images but on the remote site it could be http://your_url/your_site/images. That's one potential reason as then you'd need to either use a relative url, or /your_site/images/lu/input_bg.png.

Comment: @dash I was able to solve the problem by using your suggestion.  You should put your comment into an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Glad to help. See my answer for a couple of suggestions about how you can mirror your remote setup locally using the inbuilt web server in Visual Studio. There is also nothing to stop you from hosting IIS locally (if you are allowed to run IIS on your local machine!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, when you develop locally, Visual Studio will host the site at http://localhost:port - this is the default when using the inbuilt web server for web application and web site projects.

When you deploy to your remote site, it may be in a virtual directory that is not the root site; so, in fact, your remote application URL will be something like http://yourdomain.ext/your_site/ which changes the paths for images. The solution is to either include the virtual directory name in your path (/your_site/images/image.jpg) or use relative paths.

I prefer the former as it keeps all paths consistent, and it is possible to simulate this locally in Visual Studio.

For Web Application Projects see Solution Properties (Right click the solution node in the Solution Explorer and choose properties) - Web (tab on the left) - and look for the Virtual Path text box and change as appropriate (e.g. from '/' to '/your_site')

For Web Site Projects, click the Solution node in the Solution Explorer and look at the Properties dialog. The last option is a Virtual Path.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the url.

```
background: url("./Images/lu/input_bg.png") repeat-x scroll left bottom transparent;
```

Comment: Updated my answer see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Check your pathname on the server. Can you access the image at yoursite.com/Images/lu/input_bg.png? Is it really Images and not images?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. My image did not show up on the browser  And then I solved it. 
I added two dot begining of  my image path like this

```
<img src="../Images/icon48x48.png" alt="myLogo" width="48" height="48" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also clear your browser's cache. I had an issue where I was setting the background of a DIV using css file, and the image would only show up in firefox or IE. After I cleared chrome's cache and restarted the site, the images appeared.

If my Image is located: mysite/App_Themes/Image

and my CSS file is within App_themes reference like this: Image/myfile.css